# Setting jshint and travis-ci for javascript project

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jshint, travis-ci, grunt-contrib-jshint

I'm trying to setup Travis CI on one JavaScript project hosted on GitHub but I'm getting error like

```
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR

>> Error: Cannot find module 'jshint/src/cli/cli'
```

Those are my files:

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    jshint: {
      myFiles: ['cyrlatconverter-v0.5.4.js']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
};
```

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.10
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "node-travis",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "0.4.1",
    "grunt-cli": "0.1.9",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "0.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt --verbose"
  }
}
```

Comment: I found out that this problem might be because of your version, see : https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/issues/92 - can you upgrade and try again?

Comment: I've upped versions, and it seems to work :) But I also removed scripts part from package.json and added `grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);` to the Gruntfile.js Thanks @MaunoV.

Comment: Ok, glad to hear @Dexa :) I posted it as an answer, including your part of the findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading versions as discussed in **[github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/issues/92](http://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/issues/92)** solved the problem.

Also as @Dexa pointed out, for him - removal of `scripts` part of the **package.json** worked and adding following to the **Gruntfile.js** :

`grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);`

For clarification, ^ above registers default grunt task to run jshint when `grunt` is wrote to command line.